# Scandit not recognizing a barcode

Tags: android, scandit

I'm having trouble with a barcode using Scandit on Android (see attached). I am adding all the symbologies instead of guessing. Using version 4.14.1 of Scandit.

This same barcode was working with an old version of Scandit (don't know the version, but it was at least one year old, if not two).

The code for adding all symbologies looks like this:

```
    ScanSettings scanSettings = ScanSettings.create();
    scanSettings.setCameraFacingPreference(ScanSettings.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

    for (int sym : Barcode.ALL_SYMBOLOGIES) {
      scanSettings.setSymbologyEnabled(sym, true);
    }
```

The barcode is a CODE 128 type, and some of those do scan, but I have a couple others that don't. Even more interesting is that Scandit's demo App that's on the PlayStore can scan those ones I'm having problems with. And their latest App claims to be using 4.14.1.

Any help would be appreciated. Meanwhile I might try and contact them and see if there's a specific issue with this type of barcode.

[image: scan]

Comment: Thanks for the -1 with no comment, it's very constructive. :-|

Answer (score 1):

Turns out CODE 128 requires special settings. Just adding all symbologies is not enough. This is to enable variable length symbologies.

```
    ScanSettings scanSettings = ScanSettings.create();
    scanSettings.setCameraFacingPreference(ScanSettings.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

   // Code 128
    scanSettings.setSymbologyEnabled(Barcode.SYMBOLOGY_CODE128, true);
    SymbologySettings code128Settings = scanSettings.getSymbologySettings(Barcode.SYMBOLOGY_CODE128);
    code128Settings.setActiveSymbolCounts(
        new short[] {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
    );
```

Here's some more information about this:

http://docs.scandit.com/stable/android/android-active-symbols-counts.html
http://docs.scandit.com/stable/c_api/symbologies.html