# Unable to scan some barcodes with Scandit SDK - Android

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

My code is scanning codes of a certain length but if the length is increased it doesn't scan and I don't know how to increase the length of characters of barcode. I did check the following question but wasn't sure how to use it in my code:

[Scandit not recognizing a barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189989/scandit-not-recognizing-a-barcode)

Here is my current code:

```
    private void showCameraScannerInMatrixMode(){
    stopScanner();
    ScanSettings settings = ScanSettings.create();
    int[] symbologiesToEnable = new int[] {
            Barcode.SYMBOLOGY_CODE128
    };

    for (int sym : symbologiesToEnable) {
        settings.setSymbologyEnabled(sym, true);
    }


    settings.setMatrixScanEnabled(true);
    settings.setMaxNumberOfCodesPerFrame(10);
    settings.setCodeRejectionEnabled(true);
    float zoomLevelInPrefs = (float)PreferenceHelper.getIntFromPreferences(Constants.INLINE_SCANDIT_SCANNER_ZOOM_CONFIG,getApplicationContext());
    float zoomLevel = zoomLevelInPrefs / 100;
    settings.setRelativeZoom(zoomLevel);
    settings.setCameraFacingPreference(ScanSettings.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

    boolean emulatePortraitMode = !BarcodePicker.canRunPortraitPicker();
    if (emulatePortraitMode) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    scanTextOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mBarcodePicker = (BarcodePicker)findViewById(R.id.scannerView);
    mBarcodePicker.setOnScanListener(this);
    mBarcodePicker.applyScanSettings(settings);
    mBarcodePicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mBarcodePicker.getOverlayView().setGuiStyle(ScanOverlay.GUI_STYLE_MATRIX_SCAN);
    mBarcodePicker.getOverlayView().setVibrateEnabled(false);
    mBarcodePicker.setOnScanListener(this);
    mBarcodePicker.startScanning();
}
```

Here is the barcode that I am able to scan
[image: Here is the barcode that I am able to scan]

This I am unable to scan
[image: This I am unable to scan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant documentation for this is under https://docs.scandit.com/stable/android/android-active-symbols-counts.html what you should be doing in your case (you have a code with length 19 and one with length 22):

```
SymbologySettings symSettings = 
settings.getSymbologySettings(Barcode.SYMBOLOGY_CODE128);
short[] activeSymbolCounts = new short[] {
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22
};
symSettings.setActiveSymbolCounts(activeSymbolCounts);
```

If you aren't interested in shorter codes you might want to start a bit higher than 7. As the guide states you can download the Scandit Demo app at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scandit.demoapp to figure out the length of each code (just go into the "Any Code" mode and scan a barcode).

Comment: For the newer SDK versions (6.0+) the documentation can be found at https://docs.scandit.com/data-capture-sdk/android/configure-barcodes.html